# How can I concatenate string and a value in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new at Power Bi.

I have a value from a row 'Total Deaths'. All I want to do is concatenate a string and Total Deaths onto a card. Such as "During this incident there were 'Total Deaths' deaths"

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate things in DAX with the operator **[&](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/dax-operator-reference#text-concatenation-operator)** or with **[CONCATENATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/concatenate-function-dax)** function.

```
Measure = "During this incident there were "&SUM(Table[Total Deaths])
```

Or

```
Measure = CONCATENATE("During this incident there were ",SUM(Table[Total Deaths]))
```